# Audit revealed answer that may be salvageable

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I had originally asked about why I failed an audit, but that was clarified to me through more thorough explanation. I actually had a second part to that question that I didn't articulate properly, so this question will address that.

The audit in question:

[image: the audit post]

The audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/20913164

Original question: [Webhook configuration with Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620226/webhook-configuration-with-gitlab/)

The answer which was deleted (now undeleted): [Webhook configuration with Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620226/webhook-configuration-with-gitlab/51996610#51996610)

The answer that the audit used shows comments explaining that the answer is a link only answer, which is discouraged. While it looks like it on the *surface* due to bad formatting, I believe it is a valid answer with good intention.

At the time, the answer was deleted, so I couldn't go and update the formatting to what I believe would help improve it.

Comment: thats.. a url _format_ not a link only answer..

Comment: Just post the answer yourself, do make sure you don't make the same mistake.

Comment: @HansPassant that would strike me as a bit unfair though.

Comment: To the questioner and the many googlers that have the same problem?  Not really.  He can properly attribute the user, link to his profile.  Linking the audit seems a bit silly.

Comment: Imo the proper course would be to modflag the answer (or, if you're sub 10K, the question), and ask a mod to undelete the answer. I've seen this happen on other occasions, example API URLs tend to get deleted through review unless you format them as code. Reposting it is bad form imo, even when providing attribution. If you see an autocomment from review under such a question, please notify the reviewer about his mistake and flag the comment as no longer needed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For 10k-ers: Edit the post to be a proper, well-formatted answer, then flag for a mod to undelete.

---

For the sub-10k, there are two natural routes: either persuade a 10k user to help ([SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) might be a good place to ask), or mod-flag the question.

If you do the latter, make sure you include a *detailed* explanation of why the post is an actual answer and how it can be salvaged. Including a link to the audit is a good way to point out the exact answer in question.